How to get the feature names from a OneHotEncoder embedded in a ColumnTransformer?
How can I get the feature names from a OneHotEncoder embedded in a ColumnTransformer?
The following piece of code:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1],[2]], columns = ['C'])
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output = False)
transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', ohe, ['C'])])
transformer.fit_transform(df)
ohe.get_feature_names_out()

results in the following error message:
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-46f41a3cf71a> in <cell line: 10>()
      8 transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('encoder', ohe, ['C'])])
      9 transformer.fit_transform(df)
---> 10 ohe.get_feature_names_out()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
   1388 
   1389     if not fitted:
-> 1390         raise NotFittedError(msg % {"name": type(estimator).__name__})
   1391 
   1392 

NotFittedError: This OneHotEncoder instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

Why?

ColumnTransformer clones its transformers, so your ohe indeed remains unfitted. You can access the (fitted) components in a couple of ways, e.g.
transformer.named_transformers_["encoder"].get_feature_names_out()

Note too that the ColumnTransformer itself has a get_feature_names_out method.
